# sed - несколько нестандартных задач по переделке строки

Tags: linux, sed

Подскажите, как реализовать с помощью `sed` :

1. Поставить определенный символ после каждого знака в строке, при этом если есть пробел - то на его месте тоже, но если есть такой символ в строке - его игнорировать (не дублировать). В итоге все знаки должны чередоваться нужным символом через один:

   `Foo bar, 38-popugaev.   >   F.o.o.b.a.r.,.3.8.-.p.o.p.u.g.a.e.v.`

   `Foo bar, 38-popugaev.   >   F-o-o-b-a-r-,-3-8-p-o-p-u-g-a-e-v-.-`
2. То же, но после последнего знака не должно быть как ни этого символа, так и ни какого знака пунктуации:

   `Foo bar, 38-popugaev.   >   F.o.o.b.a.r.,.3.8.-.p.o.p.u.g.a.e.v`

   `Foo bar, 38-popugaev.   >   F-o-o-b-a-r-,-3-8-p-o-p-u-g-a-e-v`
3. Чередовать всю строку то заглавной буквой, то строчной, (как вариант наоборот), при этом игнорируя регистры самой строки:

   `Foo bar, 38-popugaev.   >   FoO bAr, 38-PoPuGaEv.`

   `Foo bar, 38-popugaev.   >   fOo BaR, 38-pOpUgAeV.`
4. То же, но при этом каждое слово в строке должно начинаться с определенного регистра, игнорируя строгую очередность все строки в пользу очередности каждого слова (первый вариант - каждое слово должно начинаться с большой буквы, затем чередование, второй вариант - с маленькой и затем чередование):

   `Foo bar, 38-popugaev.   >   FoO BaR, 38-PoPuGaEv.`

   `Foo bar, 38-popugaev.   >   fOo bAr, 38-pOpUgAeV.`

Можно и как отдельный скрипт каждый раз, чтобы запускать `sed -f script.sed`

Спасибо )

Comment: Поделитесь ссылкой на задачник ))) (я серьезно, с удовольствием порешаю)

Comment: задачник в голове )) Решайте, я еще подкину )

Comment: 2 и 3 — это ж вообще примитив. зачем они тут?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin    не все ж такие крутые, как Вы ) думаю для вас на этом сайте 98% примитив... Поправьте плиз 1). `echo "Foo bar, 38-popugaev." | sed 's/ //g;s/\S/&./g'` - `F.o.o.b.a.r.,.3.8.-.p.o.p.u.g.a.e.v...` - не совсем так получается, ну можно конечно добавить еще удаление повторов точек тут... может свой лаконичный правильный предложите?

Comment: например, так: `s/[ .]//g;s/./&./g`

Comment: Ок. спасибо. 1- понятно. 2 я так понимаю что-то типа `'s/[ .]//g;s/./&./g;s/[[:punct:]]*$//g'` ? 3,4 - вопрос остается открытым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тема достаточно старовата, но тоже поучаствую, 3 пункт:

`echo "Foo bar, 38-popugaev" | sed -r 's/([а-Яa-Z]{0,1}[^a-Zа-Я]{0,1})([а-Яa-Z]{0,1}[^a-Zа-Я]{0,1})/\U\1\L\2/g'`

> > FoO bAr, 38-PoPuGaEv

echo "Foo bar, 38-popugaev" | sed -r 's/([а-Яa-Z]{0,1}[^a-Zа-Я]{0,1})([а-Яa-Z]{0,1}[^a-Zа-Я]{0,1})/\L\1\U\2/g'

> > fOo BaR, 38-pOpUgAeV

Четвертый пункт отличается от третьего пункта лишь пробелом в исключении:

`echo "Foo bar, 38-popugaev" | sed -r 's/([а-Яa-Z]{0,1}[^a-Zа-Я ]{0,1})([а-Яa-Z]{0,1}[^a-Zа-Я ]{0,1})/\U\1\L\2/g'`

> > FoO BaR, 38-pOpUgAeV

`echo "Foo bar, 38-popugaev" | sed -r 's/([а-Яa-Z]{0,1}[^a-Zа-Я ]{0,1})([а-Яa-Z]{0,1}[^ a-Zа-Я]{0,1})/\L\1\U\2/g'`

> > fOo bAr, 38-PoPuGaEv

Answer (score 2):

можно и так, например:

```
#!/bin/bash

s='Foo bar, 38-popugaev.'
camel1='s/([[:alpha:]])([^[:alpha:]]*)([[:alpha:]])([^[:alpha:]]*)/\U\1\2\L\3\4/g'
camel2='s/([[:alpha:]])([^[:alpha:]]*)([[:alpha:]])([^[:alpha:]]*)/\L\1\2\U\3\4/g'
f1() {
  echo ${s} | sed -r "s/[ ${1}]+/${1}/g;s/./&${1}/g;s/\\${1}\\${1}//g"
}
f2() {
  f1 ${1} | sed 's/[[:punct:]]*$//'
}
f3() {
  echo ${s} | sed -r ${1}
}
f4() {
  echo ${s} | sed -r ":s;h;s/^(\W*)\n(.*)/\2\1/;to;s/^(\W*\w+).*/\1/;${1};H;g;s/^\W*\w+//;ts;bs;:o;s/\n//g"
}

echo 1
f1 "."
f1 "-"
echo 2
f2 "."
f2 "-"
echo 3
f3 ${camel1}
f3 ${camel2}
echo 4
f4 ${camel1}
f4 ${camel2}
```

вывод, например:

```
1
F.o.o.b.a.r.,.3.8.-.p.o.p.u.g.a.e.v.
F-o-o-b-a-r-,-3-8-p-o-p-u-g-a-e-v-.-
2
F.o.o.b.a.r.,.3.8.-.p.o.p.u.g.a.e.v
F-o-o-b-a-r-,-3-8-p-o-p-u-g-a-e-v
3
FoO bAr, 38-PoPuGaEv.
fOo BaR, 38-pOpUgAeV.
4
Foo Bar, 38-PoPuGaEv.
fOo bAr, 38-pOpUgAeV.
```